# How to make a 2D array of 2D arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I tried to find a solution for this through many sources. But in vain. I have 3 2D array objects:

```
double[][] W1 = new double[5][10];
double[][] W2 = new double[2][3];
double[][] W3 = new double[4][6];
```

and I want another array object to contain those 3  array objects. How do I do it?

I found that it is possible to make many 1D arrays to an array of 2D arrays using the following

```
double[][] W = new double[][]{W1, W2, W3}; //provided W1, W2, W3 are 1D arrays.
```

But how do I do the same for 2D arrays?

Comment: `double[][][] W = {W1, W2, W3};`

Comment: Your array `W` is not an array of 2D arrays, it is a 1D array of 1D arrays, also known as a 2D array. Similarly, it _sounds like_ you don't really want a 2D array of 2D arrays, you actually want a 3D array that's initialized with 3 2D arrays. In either case, the end result is just a single array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A 1D array is declared as `double[]`, i.e. `[]` of `double`.

A 1D array of 1D arrays (a 2D array) is declared as `double[][]`, i.e. `[]` of `double[]`.

A 1D array of 2D arrays (a 3D array) is declared as `double[][][]`, i.e. `[]` of `double[][]`.

A 1D array of 3D arrays (a 4D array) is declared as `double[][][][]`, i.e. `[]` of `double[][][]`.

There is no practical distinction between a 3D array, a 1D array of 2D arrays and a 2D array of 1D arrays; or between a 4D array, a 1D array of 3D arrays and a 2D array of 2D arrays. It's purely how *you* choose to think about them.

I really can't think why you'd want to use arrays nested this deeply; I'd suggest you think about whether a better alternative might be exist.

Answer (score 2):

So you want to initialize a 3D array from 3 2D arrays. That should do it

```
double[][][] W = {W1, W2, W3};
```

Note how you don't need `new`.

Comment: I dont want W to be a 3D array. it has to be a 2D array. I am basically a python programmer, and it is possible to do such stuff in python.. I wanted to know if the same is possible in java.

Comment: You want a 2D array where each element is a 2D array of doubles ? That would be a 4D array then